# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in view page getting issue laravel5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When trying to update or fetch data on edit page getting bellow issue Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in the  Form::select() area.

Below is my controller :

```
if (!$_POST) {
            $bedrooms = ["studio"];
            $bedrooms[0] = "Studio";
            $i = 1;
            while ($i < 10) {
                $beds = [];
                $i = 1;
                while ($i < 16) {
                    $bathrooms = [];
                    $bathrooms[0] = 0;
                    
                    $i = 0;
                    while ($i < 8) {
                        $accommodates = [];
                        $i = 1;
                        while ($i < 16) {
                            $data["bedrooms"] = ["studio"];
                            $data["beds"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,"16+"];
                            $data["bed_type"] = \App\Models\BedType::where("status", "Active")->pluck("name", "id");
                            $data["bathrooms"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,"8+"];
                            $data["property_type"] = \App\Models\PropertyType::where("status", "Active")->pluck("name", "id");
                            $data["room_type"] = \App\Models\RoomType::where("status", "Active")->pluck("name", "id");
                            $data["lan_description"] = \App\Models\RoomsDescriptionLang::where("room_id", $request->id)->get();
                            $data["accommodates"] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,"16+"];
                            $data["country"] = \App\Models\Country::pluck("long_name", "short_name");
                            $data["amenities"] = \App\Models\Amenities::active_all()->groupBy("type_id");
                            $data["users_list"] = \App\Models\User::pluck("first_name", "id");
                            $data["room_id"] = $request->id;
                            $data["result"] = \App\Models\Rooms::find($request->id);
                        // dd($data['result']);
                            $data["rooms_photos"] = \App\Models\RoomsPhotos::where("room_id", $request->id)->get();
                            $data["calendar"] = str_replace(["<form name=\"calendar-edit-form\">", "</form>", url("manage-listing/" . $request->id . "/calendar")], ["", "", "javascript:void(0);"], $calendar->generate($request->id));
                            $data["prev_amenities"] = explode(",", $data["result"]->amenities);
                          //  dd($data["prev_amenities"]);
                            $data["length_of_stay_options"] = \App\Models\Rooms::getLenghtOfStayOptions();
                            $data["availability_rules_months_options"] = \App\Models\Rooms::getAvailabilityRulesMonthsOptions();
                        //   dd($data);
                            return view("admin.rooms.edit", $data);
                        }
                        $accommodates[$i] = $i == 16 ? $i . "+" : $i;
                        $i++;
                    }
                    $bathrooms[(string) $i] = $i == 8 ? $i . "+" : $i;
                    $i += 0;
                }
                $beds[$i] = $i == 16 ? $i . "+" : $i;
                $i++;
            }
            $bedrooms[$i] = $i;
            $i++;
        }
```

And view file as follows:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => ADMIN_URL.'/edit_room/'.$room_id='', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'add_room_form', 'files' => true]) !!} 
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $room_id }}" name="room_id" id="room_id">
                    <div id="sf1" class="frm">
                        <fieldset class="box-body">
                            <div id="ajax_container" class="iccon">
                                {!! $calendar??'' !!}
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sf2" class="frm">
                        <p class="text-danger">
                            (*)Fields are Mandatory
                        </p>
                        <fieldset class="box-body">
                            <p class="text-success text-bold">
                                Rooms and Beds
                            </p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="bedrooms" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                                    Bedrooms
                                    <em class="text-danger">
                                        *
                                    </em>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    
                          {!! Form::select('bedrooms', $bedrooms='', $result->bedrooms, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'bedrooms', 'placeholder' => 'Select...']) !!} 
                        </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="beds" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                                    Beds
                                    <em class="text-danger">
                                        *
                                    </em>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                   {!! Form::select('beds', $beds, $result->beds, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'beds', 'placeholder' => 'Select...']) !!} 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="bed_type" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                                    Bed Type
                                    <em class="text-danger">
                                        *
                                    </em>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                  {!! Form::select('bed_type', $bed_type, $result->bed_type, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'bed_type', 'placeholder' => 'Select...']) !!} 
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I am not getting what is wrong in that. in dd($result) getting all attributes values but not getting ehy this errors comes
Current i am working on laravel5.5 version.
ANyone have idea thwn please let me know

Comment: Show you `dd($result)` output

Comment: @S N Sharma yes in attributes getting result value

Comment: Can you show here?

Comment: @S N Sharma getting result as follows

Comment: Rooms {#1386 #table: "rooms"
  #fillable: array:2 [0 => "summary"1 => "name"] #appends: array:11 [▼
  
    #attributes: array:29 [
    "id" => 10018
    "user_id" => 10001
    "name" => "Ramala house"
    "sub_name" => "Entire home/apt in Mumbai"
    "summary" => "15 rooms villa"
    "check_in_time" => "Flexible"
    "check_out_time" => "Flexible"
    "booking_message" => ""
    "property_type" => 9
    "room_type" => 1
    "is_shared" => "No"
    "accommodates" => 9
    "bedrooms" => 0
    "beds" => 10
    "bed_type" => 1
    
  ]

Comment: `bedrooms` is 0 and it is not type of Array. That is you are getting error

Comment: @SNSharma N Sharma  How to resolve this? I am not getting how to solved this? If you give suggetion then please help

Comment: What data you want to display? Is it number list or somthing else?

Comment: Why are you returning view in while loop?

Comment: @S N Sharma It is the number list of beds from user can select number